# Switching page orientation in ireport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, orientation-changes

I've read there's no way to handle mixed orientations natively using iReport, however reading the documentation I wonder if by using **JRDefaultScriptlet's beforePageInit()** it could be accomplished somehow. In my case there's a portrait front page, as many landscape pages as there's data to populate them, and a last frontal page.

On the other hand does anybody know:

- If this is a feature to be supported in the near future
- If there's an alternative that does as requested and generates a jasper-compliant xml file

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What format are you exporting to? I know with PDF you could break your report up into three seperate report files, title page, data, last page, and then do a batch PDF export. That does respect the page orientation of each individual report in the batch. I am not sure if it works with other formats though and it is kinda a hack in my opinion. It would be nice feature though.

Comment: I need to generate a single jrxml file that contains both orientations because there's another process that expects such input.

Comment: Unless you can modify that process I do not think you can do it any other way.

Comment: I am assuming here that you can not modify the process and need a solution that essentially gives you a jrxml file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I decided to play around with iReport and see what options there where for this. Turns out it is sort of possible to pull off, with some effort and imagination. This is assuming your first page is in the Title Section, and your Last Page is in the summary section.

1. Create your report in landscape mode.
2. Under Report Properties in iReport set `Title on New Page` and `Summary on New Page` to true.
3. Assuming you are using a standard 8.5" X 11" Letter sized page with all the margins set to 20, set the height of the Title and Summary sections to 572.
4. Add your static text fields into the appropriate section.
5. Now for each static text field you need to set the `Rotate` property to `Left` (well it could actually be `Right`, the point is they all need to be the same.
6. Of course add the all the other fields you want into the appropriate bands for page header, data, etc.
7. Export your report.

**Note**: if you have any images that need to go into the Title or Summary Section your will need to rotate them appropriately outside of iReport and save it. Then set the rotated image as the image in the report. Unfortunately the image tag does not seem to have a rotate property, as that would make life to easy.

Also if you do not set the properties listed in step 2 you will not be able to set the height of the Title and Summary bands to the appropriate width. If you are using a different size paper and/or 
margins the easy way to figure out the max size (which is what you will need) is to set the height of the band to a very large number. It will then popup and tell you it is to large, and what the max size actually is.

Comment: This answer is sweet. I think it's not practical in many cases... but it's still awesome.

Comment: Thanks, to be honest I feel the same way. It takes a little longer to lay everything out, since it is all tilted. I like splitting them apart, as a lot of times I find that we essentially use the same title page in multiple reports, just changing the text. But if it has to be one JRXML this is probably the only way to go, that I know of.

Comment: Great "lateral thinking" answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

There is no support to mixed landscape and portrait subreport, in the future they will add an object call JasperBook or something like that where you can add different subreports of different orientations without problems, but for the moment you have simulate that by doing different reports and join them just before showing them.

I.E.

//Create the reports separately

```
        InputStream report1 = (InputStream) getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/app/jasper/reportPortrait.jasper");
        InputStream report2 = (InputStream) getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/app/jasper/reportLandscape.jasper");
        InputStream report3 = (InputStream) getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/app/jasper/reportPortrait.jasper");

        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, map, conn);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint2 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report2, map, conn);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint3 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report3, map, conn);

        JRPdfExporter exp = new JRPdfExporter();
```

//Add the JasperPrint objects to an ArrayList

```
        List list = new ArrayList(); 

        list.add(jasperPrint);
        list.add( jasperPrint2 );
        list.add(jasperPrint3);
```

//And say to the exporter to join the list of reports.

```
        exp.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, list); 
        exp.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, response.getOutputStream());
        exp.exportReport();
```

I'm doing that in my reports and it works. Good luck!

Comment: I had mentioned that in the comments earlier, but he said he needs it as a single JRXML file. Apparently he cannot modify the process that it is fed into. Good example code though.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. I don't understand why although because you can pass all the variables like the page number, etc between the different reports. But if he want all the pages in the same JRXML your answer is obviously better