# How to rotate Jasper Report?

Tags: jasper-reports

Can anyone please help me? I want to rotate the page of my jasper report or enable the rotate button on the jasper viewer.
I tried to use the following code but it didn't work.

```
jasperPrint.setOrientation(OrientationEnum.LANDSCAPE);
```

I am using jasper reports 4.5.1..

Thanks

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970057/switching-page-orientation-in-ireport

Comment: nope,, it's not what i'm looking for. but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

There is an option you can set in the jrxml file. [Here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/landscape/index.html) you can read about it.

If you are using iReports to create the jrxml file, you can set it clicking out of any of the bands.

Comment: By default the page orientation is portrait. What I want to do is to enable the rotate or flip button in jasperViewer because it is disabled.